# Aggregate different states for timestamp periods

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with mongoDB and need make a query for search nº operations initialized, in execution and finishd for a period time (every hour or every month ...)

My json documents has following structure:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55263d62c63265b9bb138551"),
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-02-12T15:27:48.546Z"),       
  "duration" : 199821
}
```

*timestamp* field  is the procces init start and *duration* is the execution time in milliseconds. If i add timestamp + duration = finish timestamp

I can group the number of operations (10 min) that are in a period of time with this query:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$match" :{ 
    "timestamp":{ "$gte": ISODate("2015-0427T12:00:00.0Z") }
  }},
  { "$group" :{
    "_id": { 
      "dayOfMonth":{ "$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp" },
      "month":{ "$month": "$timestamp" }, 
      "hour": { "$hour":"$timestamp" },
      "time": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$minute":"$timestamp" },
          { "$mod": [{ "$minute": "$timestamp" }, 10] }
        ]
      }
    },
    "count":{ "$sum":1 }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id.time": 1 } }
])
```

But I also need number of "in execution", and "finised".

I tried with mapreduce, and other aggregation queries but I cannot get a simmilar result to:

```js
{
 _id: {
  "month" : 03,
  "minute" : 00,
  "Initialized" : 6,
  "InExecution" : 10,
  "Finished": 5
  }
_id: {
  "month" : 03,
  "minute" : 10,
  "Initialized" : 4,
  "InExecution" : 12,
  "Finished": 4
  }
_id: {
  "month" : 03,
  "minute" : 20,
  "Initialized" : 3,
  "InExecution" : 8,
  "Finished": 5
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tough issue to understand, but there is one main problem the the "aggregation framework" here and it's mainly that your "activities" live in several different time intervals depending on it's present state.

What that means is that there is always a "start" and a "finish" interval it belongs in as well as possibly "several" intervals in which the task can be considered "in execution".

The aggregation framework cannot really do that in a single pass. But you can do it with mapReduce:

```js
db.test.mapReduce(
  function() {
     // Work out time values
     var finished = this.timestamp.valueOf() + this.duration,
         finishedInterval = finished -
           ( finished % ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) ),
         interval = this.timestamp.valueOf() -
           ( this.timestamp.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) );

     // Emit initialized
     emit(       
       {
         "year": new Date(interval).getUTCFullYear(),
         "month": new Date(interval).getUTCMonth()+1,
         "day": new Date(interval).getUTCDate(),
         "hour": new Date(interval).getUTCHours(),
         "minute": new Date(interval).getUTCMinutes()
       },
       {
           "Initialized": 1,
           "InExecution": 0,
           "Finshed": 0
       }
     );

     // Emit finished
     emit(       
       {
         "year": new Date(finishedInterval).getUTCFullYear(),
         "month": new Date(finishedInterval).getUTCMonth()+1,
         "day": new Date(finishedInterval).getUTCDate(),
         "hour": new Date(finishedInterval).getUTCHours(),
         "minute": new Date(finsihedInterval).getUTCMinutes()
       },
       {
           "Initialized": 0,
           "InExecution": 0,
           "Finshed": 1
       }
     );

     // Emit In execution for every 10 minute interval until finished
     if ( ( interval + ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) ) < finishedInterval ) {
       for ( var x = interval; x<finishedInterval; x+= ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) ) {
         emit(
           {
             "year": new Date(x).getUTCFullYear(),
             "month": new Date(x).getUTCMonth()+1,
             "day": new Date(x).getUTCDate(),
             "hour": new Date(x).getUTCHours(),
             "minute": new Date(x).getUTCMinutes()
           },
           {
             "Initialized": 0,
             "InExecution": 1,
             "Finshed": 0
           }
         );
       }
     }
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var result = { "Initialized": 0, "InExecution": 0, "Finshed": 0 };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      Object.keys(value).forEach(function(key) {
          result[key] += value[key];          
      });         
    });

    return result;
  },
  { 
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "query": { "timestamp": { "$gte": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z") } }
  }
)
```

As you can see, most of the work is done in the mapper. This basically works out which interval the task "started" and "ended" in and emits the appropriate data for that.

Then of course by working from the "start" interval of the task, emit an "in execution" count for every 10 minute interval while that value is less that the "end" interval of the task.

The reducer simply takes all emitted counts for each interval and adds them up. So that's a very simple operation.

---

The map and reduce logic is sound, but there is a problem with the query selection logic in that jobs "finshing" or "in execution" are likely going to be started before the first query time.

In order to do that you need to fix that query selection to consider that, and since you don't store the "finish" time you need to calculate that, and this means JavaScript evaluation in the query with [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```js
{
  "out": { "inline": 1 },
  "query": {
    "$where": function() {
      return (this.timestamp >= new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z") ||
        new Date(this.timestamp.valueOf() + this.duration) >=
          new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z"))
    }
  }
}
```

That picks up the items that were still running before the start time of the query or finishing at that time.

It's not great since that scans the collection so it would be better to include "finshed" as a value in your data to make the query selection easier:

```js
{
  "out": { "inline": 1 },
  "query": {
     "$or": [
         { "timestamp": { "$gte": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z") } },
         { "finished": { "$gte": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z") } }
     ]
  }
}
```

That can use an "index" and be much faster.

---

As a final thing, there would still be values emitted "before" the "timestamp" filter value here since "finished" in either form means tasks that started before that time. Also it's a good idea to put an "end" time on the query conditions and logic for the same reasons.

For this again alter the options block to include "scope" vars to be used in the execution logic, and also add to the "query" conditions:

```js
{
  "out": { "inline": 1 },
  "query": {
    "$or": [
      { 
        "timestamp": { 
          "$gte": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z"),
          "$lt": new Date("2015-04-28T12:00:00Z")
        }
      },
      { 
        "finished": { 
          "$gte": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z"),
          "$lt": new Date("2015-04-28T12:00:00Z")
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "scope": {
      "start": new Date("2015-04-27T12:00:00Z"),
      "finsh": new Date("2015-04-28T12:00:00Z")
  }
}
```

Then add conditions around each emit, first for started where "interval" is greater than "start":

```js
     // Emit initialized
     if ( interval >= start.valueOf() ) {
       emit(
```

And finsihed where "finishedInterval" is less than "finish":

```js
     // Emit finished
     if ( finishedInterval <= finish.valueOf() ) {
       emit(
```

And then limit the loops on "in execution" as well:

```js
     // Emit In execution for every 10 minute interval until finished
     if ( ( interval + ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) ) < finishedInterval ) {
     for ( var x = interval; (( x<finishedInterval ) && ( x<finish.valueOf() )); x+= ( 1000 * 60 * 10 ) ) {
       if ( x > start.valueOf() ) {
         emit(
```

That gives you a clean start and end point while keeping all the statistics possible listed in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Blakes,

For your big interest. I've been study your solution and think good idea.

I found a possible solution with aggregation framework.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
{$match:{ 
           "timestamp":{$exists: true, "$gte": ISODate("2015-03-27T12:00:00.0Z") },              
         } },
{ $project: {
    _id: 1,
    timestamp : 1,
    error: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$severidad", "ERROR"]}, 1, 0]},

    init: {$cond: [ {$and : [{$eq: [{"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":"$timestamp"},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":"$timestamp"}, 10]}
                                ]}, {"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":"$timestamp"},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":"$timestamp"}, 10]}
                                ]}]}, {$ne: ["$severidad", "ERROR"]}]}, 1, 0]},

    executing: {$cond: [ {$and : [{$gt: [{"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":{ $add: [ "$timestamp", "$datos_aplicacion.duracion"]}},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":{ $add: [ "$timestamp", "$datos_aplicacion.duracion"]}}, 10]}
                                ]}, {"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":"$timestamp"},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":"$timestamp"}, 10]}
                                ]}]}, {$ne: ["$severidad", "ERROR"]}]}, 1, 0]},

    finished: {$cond: [ {$and : [{$eq: [{"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":{ $add: [ "$timestamp", "$datos_aplicacion.duracion"]}},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":{ $add: [ "$timestamp", "$datos_aplicacion.duracion"]}}, 10]}
                                ]}, {"$subtract": [
                                    {"$minute":"$timestamp"},
                                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":"$timestamp"}, 10]}
                             ]}]}, {$ne: ["$severidad", "ERROR"]}]}, 1, 0]},                                    
    }}, 
{$group :{_id: { 

        dayOfMonth:{"$dayOfMonth":"$timestamp"}, month:{"$month":"$timestamp"}, hour:{"$hour":"$timestamp"} ,
        time: {
                "$subtract": [
                    {"$minute":"$timestamp"},
                    {"$mod": [{"$minute":"$timestamp"}, 10]}
                ]
            },            
    },
    NumError: {$sum:"$error"},
    NumInit:{$sum:"$init"},
    NumExecuting:{$sum:"$executing"},
    NumFinished:{$sum:"$finished"}        

    }},
{ $sort : { "_id": 1} });
```

It takes 1,2 sec with 1M of records

Regards,

Comment: If you study the content of the answer I gave you should realize that these results are not the same. "Finished" will only be the jobs that started and finshed in the speicified period. The same is said for "in execution" in that it only reports that a job from the period is executing then only in that period. If either type "crosses the boundary" ( and that can be a matter of milliseconds ) then it would not be picked up. That is why mapReduce was chosen for the answer and I took the time to explain those points.